# Setting window.location.hash to null in Safari 3+ causes it to be set to #

Tags: javascript, browser, safari, location

Setting window.location.hash to null in Safari 3+ causes it to be set to #, e.g.

> window.location.hash = '#foo' => #foo

But,

> window.location.hash = null => #

Same occurs if you set it to an empty string instead of null. Behavior definitely occurs in Safari 3 + 4, and does *not* occur in FF 3 or 4.

Any workarounds for this? Granted, it is more of an aesthetically-motivated thing, but I'd still like consistent behavior across all browsers.

Comment: There's no FF 4 (as of now). In FF 3.5.2, setting hash to `null` also appends '#' to url. For consistent behavior, I would advise to assign only string values to hash. Coercing `null` to '' before assignment is trivial enough.

Answer (score 0):

In Safari 4 (don't know about 3) this will make the # disappear, and the page will not reload.

```
window.location.hash = 'foo';
window.history.go(-1);
```

However, it will obviously mess with the browser history. If they click forward it will take them to http://whatever.com/#foo.

Comment: This is quite an incomplete solution. It does not work if the original URL had a hash in it and you wanted to remove it.

Comment: That's because there is no complete solution as far as I know, feel free to enlighten us otherwise. This is obviously just a hack and not meant to be super robust.

Answer (score 0):

Set hash to an empty string, not null. Null is not a valid value for the hash property (which is always a string). Works for me in Safari 3.2.1/Win. (Though not, for some reason in Opera 10... but then who cares? Is having a blank hash part on the end of the URL such a bad thing?)

Comment: setting location.hash = ''; will still leave the # sign in the url, which is what he's trying to avoid.